# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException

Tags: android, android-layout

In my application I am creating a database and when I click the send button it should be inserted into database. For the first record it is not showing any error but when I insert more, it force closes with the following exception:

```
02-17 15:38:56.480: WARN/dalvikvm(10538): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
02-17 15:38:56.500: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10538): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-17 15:38:56.500: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10538): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 4
02-17 15:38:56.500: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10538):     at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:329)
02-17 15:38:56.500: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10538):     at com.A_PJTMANAGER.pkg.A_PJTMANAGERact$EfficientAdapter.getView(A_PJTMANAGERact.java:174)
02-17 15:38:56.500: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10538):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1315)
02-17 15:38:56.500: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10538):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1727)
02-17 15:38:56.500: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10538):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:652)
02-17 15:38:56.500: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10538):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:709)
02-17 15:38:56.500: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10538):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1580)
02-17 15:38:56.500: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10538):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1147)
02-17 15:38:56.500: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10538):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
02-17 15:38:56.500: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10538):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:909)
02-17 15:38:56.500: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10538):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
02-17 15:38:56.500: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10538):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:909)
02-17 15:38:56.500: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10538):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
02-17 15:38:56.500: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10538):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
02-17 15:38:56.500: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10538):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
02-17 15:38:56.500: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10538):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1249)
02-17 15:38:56.500: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10538):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1125)
02-17 15:38:56.500: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10538):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1042)
02-17 15:38:56.500: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10538):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
02-17 15:38:56.500: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10538):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
02-17 15:38:56.500: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10538):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
02-17 15:38:56.500: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10538):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1045)
02-17 15:38:56.500: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10538):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
02-17 15:38:56.500: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10538):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-17 15:38:56.500: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10538):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-17 15:38:56.500: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10538):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-17 15:38:56.500: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10538):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-17 15:38:56.500: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10538):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-17 15:38:56.500: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10538):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-17 15:38:56.500: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10538):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-17 15:38:56.500: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10538):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`
```

Comment: Line 174 in A_PJTMANAGERact.java you do `someVector.elementAt(4)` but that Vector has no 5th element.

Comment: i didnt understand if i enter second record it is saying arrayindexoutofrange :2,   if i enter third record it is saying arrayindexoutofrange :3 but in line 174 i kept  Log.i("name",""+NAME.elementAt(position)); it is showing error in that line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:329)
```

this error in logcat that means you are using Vector and when get value from vector, index is higher vector size

Comment: @user1083266: If you solved the issue using this answer, mark it as accepted. If you found another way, please share by adding yourself an answer and accepting it, so others can use the information. I know it is late and maybe you forgot how you managed it, but try to share information in the future, to help others.